# Notepad++ and regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am doing some test with Find in Notepad++ using regex. Here is my problem that I can't figure out why:

My text is:

```
abc/xyz/p234/s-sdf
```

The following regex matches well:

```
[a-z]+/[a-z]+(/p[0-9]+)/s-[a-z]+
```

But why the following regex (with an added '?') does not match anymore:

```
[a-z]+/[a-z]+(/p[0-9]+)?/s-[a-z]+
```

Am I right that in the last regex, the '?' means that (/p[0-9]+) can appear zero or one time?

Comment: Yes, the `?` mean the preceding token (`p[0-9]+`) can either appear, or not appear...

Comment: So why the last regex does not match the text??

Comment: Both regex match your sample. Are you *sure* notepad does not too?

Comment: Well you can try it on yours to doublecheck. On mine, the second regex doesn't match!

Comment: The second pattern matches on regex101: http://regex101.com/r/uT1lP6/1

Comment: So that's Notepad++'s problem. Thanks!

Comment: Both pattern match the text on mine. Make sure that the cursor is at the start of the file/text when you use regex find, because regex find on N++ can find something only after the position of the cursor (N++ version 6.6.8).

Comment: Alright, I was using NPP 5.9.8 and the second doesn't match. I have updated to 6.6.9 and both match now! Thanks! (PS: yes I always move the cursor to the beginning of the file before going)

Comment: @kien I would add that as an answer and self-accept. It may help others in the future.

Comment: Hi yes I wanted too but ..how to mark a comment as answer? Sorry I am a newbie!